# Take windows with you when switching desktop

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I noticed that ctrl alt up/down-arrow (which switches desktop) doesn't work when holding windows... it would be very useful to be able to bring window with you like that, does anyone know it this is possible (with or without extensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> in the meanwhile. The window with focus will come with you.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Up/Down arrow.